Asset validation failed - Distribution failed with errors
I get this error when I am uploading a build to AppStore.
I have Xcode 14.2, and macOS - Monterey
I want to upload my build with this Xcode and OS version only.


I am writing solution and reason behind this error dialogue.
Warning From Apple to all the developers:-

Starting April 29, 2024, all iOS and iPadOS apps must be built with the iOS 17 SDK or later, included in Xcode 15 or later, in order to be uploaded to App Store Connect or submitted for distribution.

Refrences:-
Apple News - https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=fxu2qp7b
Developer Forum - https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/747459

Solution:- Try to use latest everything

Latest, Xcode 15 or Upper version
Latest, macOS

And, read instruction at the time of uploading which I have mentioned in the first line.
